# Filtering Out Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make my command but don't know how to filter this output. This is the code:

```
@client.command()
async def userjoindate(ctx, username):
    user = await roblox.get_user_by_username(username)
    response = requests.get(f'https://users.roblox.com/v1/users/{user.id}')
    json_data = json.loads(response.text)
    joindate = json_data['created']
    await ctx.send(joindate)
```

If the user's id is for example 1 it will show this output:

> 2006-02-27T21:06:40.3Z

I want it just to be 2006-02-27

Comment: Is 2006-02-27T21:06:40.3Z the value of the joindate variable?

Comment: Slice out the first 10 characters? Parse it to a datetime and extract the date part?

Comment: Yes it is and also could you upvote this question and i mean to slice out the right part i only need "2006-02-27"

Comment: Look into [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It will parse the datetime string into a `datetime` object, then you can use [strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method to pick what you need.

Comment: Alright thanks also nice username

Answer (score 0):

Use slice all characters after the date.

```
slice(None, 10, None)
```